# Incorrect this in backbone binding

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.eventbinder

```
 DM.Backbone.View.feedback = Backbone.View.extend( {
     initialize: function (){
        this.render( this.model.get( 'data' ) || [] );
     },
     render: function ( param ){
        if ( $( '.problem_report_reply' ).length > 0 ) {
            _.bind( this.mail_to, this );
            $( '.problem_report_reply' ).off().on( 'click', this.mail_to )
        }
     },
     mail_to: function (){

        console.log( 'this', this )
     } );
```

Here my code of **Backbone.View**. I have problem with binding method to DOM element, **console.log** show this like a DOM element which i clicked. I use undescore method **_.bind** to correct binding *this*, what a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) creates a new function, it doesn't modify an existing one. You could use it like this

```
render: function ( param ){
    var func;

    if ( $( '.problem_report_reply' ).length > 0 ) {
        func = _.bind(this.mail_to, this);
        $('.problem_report_reply').off().on('click', func);
    }
}
```

Or use [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll), which does modify the functions in an object

```
DM.Backbone.View.feedback = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (){
        _.bindAll(this, "mail_to");
        this.render( this.model.get( 'data' ) || [] );
    },
    render: function ( param ){
        if ( $( '.problem_report_reply' ).length > 0 ) {
            $( '.problem_report_reply' ).off().on('click', this.mail_to)
        }
    },
    mail_to: function (){
        console.log( 'this', this )
    }
});
```